# How can I create an ODB connection from SPSS to save or append data into an excel or access file?

Tags: syntax, odbc, syntax-error, export-to-excel, spss

Using `Windows 64 bit OS`, `32-bit ODBC administrator`, `SPSS version 20`.

I have written the following syntax:

```
SAVE TRANSLATE /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=Excel Files; DBQ=C:\Users\AppendTest.xlsx; DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;'
  /ENCRYPTED
  /MISSING=IGNORE
  /Append
  /TABLE='Sheet1'.
```

The intention of this syntax is to append data into an excel file present in the `C:\Users\AppendTest.xlsx` location.

However, I get the following error message:

> Error# 6492: ODBC subsystem has issued an error which prevents the
>   processing of SAVE TRANSLATE ODBC request.

Also, the error read:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I am not sure about the `driverID` part of the syntax as well.

I also tried going to `FILE > EXPORT TO DATABASE` , but there is no option here to append data into an excel or access file.

Here is a snapshot of my ODBC admin:

[image: Here is a picture of my OBDC admin:]

The same exists in my User DSN as well.

My question is how can I configure/setup my system or SPSS to export/append data into an excel or access file through an ODB connection.